# From mod_rewrite to isapi_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

I have a Modx htaccess file which needs to be rewritten from `mod_rewrite` to `isapi_rewrite` 2.

Can someone please help me? The following lines need to be changed for `isapi_rewrite` 2:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^(manager|assets) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it?  ISAPI Rewrite uses a very similar syntax to mod_rewrite.  I don't believe Options, RewriteEngine or RewriteBase are supported, however, but I could be wrong.  There is a similar property to RewriteBase - UriMatchPrefix, but RewriteEngine is not mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using [ISAPI_Rewrite v3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) as it has 99% mod_rewrite compatible syntax (from the above config only Options won't work) while ISAPI_Rewrite v2 doesn't support "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" and some other directives.

Also if you are on IIS 7 (7.5) you may use [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) which implements 30+ Apache modules (including [mod_rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/mod_rewrite.htm)) on Windows systems. Ape will support the above config as is, without any modifications.

Comment: Helicon Ape can also be installed on IIS6 on windows server 2003 
http://helicontech.blogspot.com/2009/03/using-helicon-ape-under-iis6-windows.html